# UITextView text color always black on iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitextview

Whenever I try to set `TextColor`, it has no effect.

```
NotesText.TextColor = UIColor.White;
NotesText.Text = notes;
```

Setting the text color in a storyboard- or XIB-file also has no effect

I have tested this on an iPhone 4, and had reports of this happening on iPhone 5 as well.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in <s>Xamarin.</s>iOS.

If you switch the statements, so that the text content is set before the text color, it suddenly works.

```
NotesText.Text = notes;
NotesText.TextColor = UIColor.White;
```

I guess in storyboards and XIB-files, Xamarin internally sets the text color before the content text, so the bug manifests.

EDIT:

This seems to be the same issue as this: [UITextView text color not getting set when disabled selectable property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27677024/403018). So this isn't Xamarin specific, but a bug in iOS.