# UITextView is changing color in iPhone 6+ automatically which is not required

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have set the color of the text of `UITextView` from storyboard to white color. Its working fine in iPhone 5,5s,6,6s (iOS version 10.1.1) but the color is automatically getting changed to black in iPhone 6s (iOS version 9.1.1). I also provided the text color through code, then also its not working.

Comment: What is the iOS version in iPhone 6s? And what is the iOS version on other devices? I might be related to iOS rather than iPhone.

Comment: yes the versions are different.

Comment: What versions are they?

Comment: the one's working fine are iOS 10.1.1
and iPhone 6+ is iOS 9.3.3

Comment: You should edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug from Apple's part probably in iOS 9.3.3, and it was fixed for later version of iOS, as you say it is working fine in iOS 10.1.1. You can also look into another [stack overflow's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40081644/327565) with similar issue